# Yeoman component vs vendor files and upgrading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

Exploring Yeoman, and like to know how can I update a package.

I initialized an angular project

```
yeoman init angular
```

the version included in `app/script/vendor` (which also included in `index.html`) is AngularJS `v1.0.1`

How can I upgrade to AngularJS `v1.0.2`, which is the latest.

There is a command `yeoman update` , but that only updating the packages installed through yeoman. The packages installed through yeoman lives in `app/components`.

So, the questions are

1. Why there is a `vendor` and `components` folder.
2. How can upgrade Angular to latest version (without breaking whatever dependency management yeoman provides)

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are planning to make generators fetch dependencies from [Bower](https://github.com/twitter/bower) (package manager which we use under the covers) when available there. This mean you'll be able to do `yeoman update angular` to get the latest.

Answer (score -1):

Yeoman probably will never upgrade your included angular library with the latest one. It shouldnt do either. Consider this, if you include library A and start developing with it, after sometime ( say a period of 6 months or so! ) you do an update and if yeoman goes ahead and updates the version of the library you have included, that could lead to bugs and compatibility issues on your app. If on the other hand, you include the latest file, run all your tests and then are sure that the latest file changes are still plausible, then you could do it.Also, its just a one line change, why would you want yeoman to do that? Its been built to "generate" new projects based on best practices and not probably for modifying existing ones.